# Mapping frequencies to loudness using the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

I want to detect played notes and chords using the Web Audio API (using the microphone as an input device). Before I can analyse the data, I need it the individual frequencies mapped to their loudness. I started with the following snippet:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
});
const context = new AudioContext();
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
const analyser = context.createAnalyser();

const data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);
```

`data` now is an array of values between `0` to `255`. The question I have now is how can I map the frequencies to the loudness values of the data array?

Ideally, I'd like an object like this:

```js
{
    ...
    438: 128,
    439: 200,
    440: 255,
    441: 200,
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in `data[k]` corresponds to the frequency `k * Nyquist/frequencyBinCount` where `Nyquist` is one half of the sampling frequency, `AudioContext.sampleRate`.

I think that's what you're asking for.  If not please clarify.